# Compiler internal error. Process terminated with exit code 3

Tags: intellij-idea, exit-code

I am using Intellij 9.0.4 I checked out a project from SVN, set up tomcat (its running locally), and now I am trying to Make (or Compile) but it keeps giving me **Error:Compiler internal error. Process terminated with exit code 3**. I have searched the internet and couldn't get this type exit code 3.

Do you have any idea? Or which log file should I have to check to see details of the problem?
Thanks

**SOLVED**: I got it. Just increase the maximum heap size of the compiler(Setting->Compiler->Java Compiler)

Comment: It's a javac error, so you can also try changing the compiler (Setting->Compiler->Java Compiler).

Comment: I think you haven't seen the "SOLVED" part on my question. Though Thanks.

Comment: I have seen that. Just adding to the common knowledge. You can also answer your own question instead of adding "SOLVED".

Comment: I couldn't because, at that time since I was a new user, the system responded I couldn't answer my own question within 8 hours because of my reputation, I think. I forgot to do that latter on. Any ways thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

SOLVED: I got it. Just increase the maximum heap size of the compiler(Setting->Compiler->Java Compiler)

Comment: I got the same error , the problem was because windows firewall was blocking some features for idea.